# Garbage data in simple struct from C# to C++ via PInvoke

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I have a simple Size struct which is defined as

```
#pragma pack(push, 8)
struct Size final
{
public:
  std::int32_t Width = 0;
  std::int32_t Height = 0;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

In C++ and as

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 8)]
public class Size
{
    public System.Int32 Width { get; set; }
    public System.Int32 Height { get; set; }
}
```

In C#.

Now, I'm trying to create a C# Size object and send it to the C++ code, for that I have this function in C++

```
extern "C" {
__declspec(dllexport) auto Test(Common::Size size) -> void;
}

auto Test(const Common::Size size) -> void
{
    // Do something
}
```

and a PInvoke C# function to call it as:

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "Test")]
public static extern void Test(Common.Size size);
```

To wrap it up, I do call the Test function with this code:

```
var outputSize = new Common.Size() { Width = 100, Height = 200 };
PluginApi.Test(outputSize);
```

Now, what I would expect is to the parameter size in the C++ function to have the values 100 and 200 to Width and Height respectively, but what I get is garbage number, to be more exact, 132313736 for Width and 0 to Height.

What I'm doing wrong in this case?

Comment: I think it has to do with `public class Size`, which may introduce a "header" for each object holding, for example, type information (a "vtable pointer" if you want). So the memory layout of an object in c# and an instance of the struct in C will probably not match. Have you tried using a struct in C#?

Comment: You are totally right! That was a big oversight from my part.. Changing it to struct solves it! Can you add your comment as a answer so I can flag it as resolved? Thanks a lot

Comment: It will solve the problem, but for a completely different reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with `public class Size` in C#, which may introduce a "header" for each object holding, for example, type information (a "vtable pointer" if you want). So the memory layout of an object in c# and an instance of the struct in C++ will probably not match.

Using a struct in C# instead of a class should solve the problem.

Comment: Not correct. The real difference is that c# class is marshaled as a reference, i.e. a pointer, and c# struct is marshaled as a value.